# Keep formatting on an excel cell

Tags: c#, excel, automation, vsto

Basically I would like to keep the existing format of an Excel cell.
If I use
ActiveCell.Value2 = "new value";

The ActiveCell displays "new value" but loses the user defined formatting ( say red font, blue background), all formatting values goes back to Excel default format values.

Note: If you replace a cell value using Excel, Excel keeps the user's format.
When recording this action as a macro, Excel uses the property FormulaR1C1 but according to MSDN this a property used for macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I use ActiveCell.Value2 = "new value"
>   the ActiveCell displays "new value" but loses the user defined formatting

No, it does not, I just tested it (with Excel 2003). Opened a new empty document, formatted a column with some colors and user defined number format and and entered

```
ActiveCell.Value2="1"
```

in the immediate Window of the VBA editor. The existing format is kept intact. So if you have another scenario to deal with (where the format gets lost), please describe it in detail.

EDIT: if this behaviour is really different in VSTO, as a workaround, you can try to save the relevant format information of the ActiveCell before changing the value, for example

```
fci = ActiveCell.Range.Font.ColorIndex
ici = ActiveCell.Range.Interior.ColorIndex
pat = ActiveCell.Range.Interior.Pattern
nf = ActiveCell.Range.NumberFormat
```

then change the value

```
ActiveCell.Value2 = "new value"
```

and afterwards reassign the format info again

```
ActiveCell.Range.Font.ColorIndex = fci
ActiveCell.Range.Interior.ColorIndex = ici
ActiveCell.Range.Interior.Pattern = pat
ActiveCell.Range.NumberFormat = nf
```

(but beware, this is 'air code').

Comment: I think the problem only occurs with using Excel through C# - in VBA it works fine. (The question is tagged C# and VSTO but doesn't actually mention it in the question :0)

Comment: Sorry, I am using VSTO and C# and I found this behaviour annoying.
This solution does not help because I need to render a report with multiple row and columns (100s)

Comment: You were right, value2 does not change the formatting, there was range.clear call somewhere in the code that was clearing content and formatting.

Comment: awesome, it works, but how did you get the air code?

Comment: @123iamking: using autocompletion in the "Immediate" Window of the VBA editor (or directly in the code editor) helps me to figur out the syntax of commands. And if that does not help: F1 is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to copy the cell and "Paste" the formatting back - http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=56324

Comment: I will keep this idea in mind for another feature request that ai need to do, thank you for your help